# AmStockChart by json did not display

Tags: mysql, json, amcharts

I want to use AmChart and getting data for charts from MySQL by JSON.
But it display not things.

This is my js source:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 var chart2;
         $(document).ready(function(){
           $.getJSON("data",  function (data) {
                chart2.dataProvider = data;  
                chart2.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-DD-MM"; 
                chart2.validateData();
            });

         });
 var chart2 = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv2", {
    type: "stock",
    theme: "none",
    pathToImages: "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",


    dataSets: [{
            title: "Participants",
            fieldMappings: [{
              fromField: "student",
              toField: "student"
             }],
            categoryField: "date"
         }
     ],
     dataDateFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD",
     panels: [{
        showCategoryAxis: false,
        title: "Student",
        percentHeight: 70,

    stockGraphs: [{
        id: "g1",
        valueField: "student",
        comparable: true,
        compareField: "student",
        balloonText: "[[title]]:<b>[[student]]</b>",
        compareGraphBalloonText: "[[title]]:<b>[[student]]</b>"
    }],

    stockLegend: {
        periodValueTextComparing: "[[percents.student.close]]%",
        periodValueTextRegular: "[[value.close]]"
    }
}],

    chartScrollbarSettings: {
      graph: "g1"
},

chartCursorSettings: {
    valueBalloonsEnabled: true,
    fullWidth: true,
    cursorAlpha: 0.1,
    valueLineBalloonEnabled: true,
    valueLineEnabled: true,
    valueLineAlpha: 0.5
},

periodSelector: {
    position: "left",
    periods: [{
        period: "MM",
        selected: true,
        count: 1,
        label: "1 month"
    }, {
        period: "YYYY",
        count: 1,
        label: "1 year"
    }, {
        period: "YTD",
        label: "YTD"
    }, {
        period: "MAX",
        label: "MAX"
    }]
},

    dataSetSelector: {
        position: "left"
    }
});
</script>
```

The json file output from data function

```
[{"date":"2011-01-10","student":"100"},{"date":"2012-02-11","student":"122"}]
```

Anyone know the solution please help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any reason using Stockcharts not normal ones? Normal charts would be sufficient for your data format.

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse your data,

For Eg,

```
 $.getJSON("data",  function (data) {
```

> newData=JSON.parse(data);

```
                chart2.dataProvider = newData;  
                chart2.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-DD-MM"; 
                chart2.validateData();
            });
```